# jQuery Links have to be clicked twice to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, hyperlink

I have a few links on my sidebar on my website. The links have the class sidebarelement. Everytime I click one of them I have to click twice to scroll to my content. After the first time nothing happens. I use jQuery.

```
$(".sidebarelement").on("click", function () {
    var offset = $(':target').offset();
    if (offset) {
        var scrollto = offset.top - 158; // minus fixed header height
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: scrollto});
    }
});
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For everyone else who had this problem I got a solution.

The idea is to get the href attribute from the link which has been clicked and animate (scroll) to that place. Also note that e.preventDefault() prevents the link to jump to his place.

Here is my code snippet.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sidebarelement').on("click", function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(href).offset().top - document.getElementById('navDiv').clientHeight // minus fixed header height
        }, 'slow');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```